# GCP Scheduler Error: function execution failed. Details: Attribute 'label' missing from payload

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am following this tutorial in GCP, to make scraper run with schedule.
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule

Seems like it flow works in a row of
1) Scheduler
2) PubSub 
3) Function
4) Compute instance

but when i wanted to try whether it is working, it keeps shows an error of

```
gcloud functions call stopInstancePubSub \              
    --data '{"data":"eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtd2VzdDEtYiIsImluc3RhbmNlIjoid29ya2RheS1pbnN0YW5jZSJ9Cg=="}'
error: |-
  Error: function execution failed. Details:
  Attribute 'label' missing from payload
```

but nowhere i can find the answer to fill the label into the payload, and i don't know what is happening here.

GCP tutorial sucks...

Can anybody help me with this?

p.s) when i do the npm test

```
➜  scheduleinstance git:(master) npm test

> cloud-functions-schedule-instance@0.1.0 test /Users/yoonhoonsang/Desktop/nodejs-docs-samples/functions/scheduleinstance
> mocha test/*.test.js --timeout=20000



  functions_start_instance_pubsub
    ✓ startInstancePubSub: should accept JSON-formatted event payload with label (284ms)
Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.
    at GoogleAuth.getApplicationDefaultAsync (/Users/yoonhoonsang/Desktop/nodejs-docs-samples/functions/scheduleinstance/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:160:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async GoogleAuth.getClient (/Users/yoonhoonsang/Desktop/nodejs-docs-samples/functions/scheduleinstance/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:502:17)
    at async GoogleAuth.authorizeRequest (/Users/yoonhoonsang/Desktop/nodejs-docs-samples/functions/scheduleinstance/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/googleauth.js:543:24)
    ✓ startInstancePubSub: should fail with missing 'zone' attribute
    ✓ startInstancePubSub: should fail with missing 'label' attribute
    ✓ startInstancePubSub: should fail with empty event payload

  functions_stop_instance_pubsub
    ✓ stopInstancePubSub: should accept JSON-formatted event payload with label
    ✓ stopInstancePubSub: should fail with missing 'zone' attribute
    ✓ stopInstancePubSub: should fail with missing 'label' attribute
    ✓ stopInstancePubSub: should fail with empty event payload
```

Comment: The error message comes from the code in `index.js` because you probably did not encode the payload correctly. This is an example where you should not include pictures and you should copy and paste the actual error. The payload that you created is base64 and we cannot decode that from a picture. You should base64 enocde something similar to `{"zone":"us-west1-b", "label":"env=dev"}`

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question in the way you commented. However I can't find the way to encode the payload correctly, since there were not much materials on google. Can you guide me somehow?

Thank you very much for the comment

Comment: Your payload decoded: `{"zone":"us-west1-b","instance":"workday-instance"}`. That does not match what the code expects. Look at the example in my comment again. Base64 encoding is very simple and there are many articles on the Internet.

Comment: wow I have solved the problem!! Thanks for your help John. 
I wonder why the 'tutorial' is not working on GCP... By some modification and comments of yours made my life easier

Comment: Glad you solved it. Post an answer with your solution. Also, show the correct payload and how you encoded it so that everyone benefits.

Comment: Hey @윤훈상, can you post your solution as answer for greater visibility to other community users who might run into the same issue? Looking forward to that. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted the solution, which is very similar to life saver, @JohnHanley. But I added more explanation of situation and solutions to the similar problem. Thank you guys all.

Answer (score 0):

John Hanley from the comments above:

> The error message comes from the code in index.js because you probably did not encode the payload correctly. This is an example where you should not include pictures and you should copy and paste the actual error. The payload that you created is base64 and we cannot decode that from a picture. You should base64 enocde something similar to {"zone":"us-west1-b", "label":"env=dev"}
>
> Your payload decoded: {"zone":"us-west1-b","instance":"workday-instance"}. That does not match what the code expects. Look at the example in my comment again. Base64 encoding is very simple and there are many articles on the Internet. –

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JohnHanley, I solved the problem of my question, and I am giving the solutions incase that other people could experience the same problem, since Google Tutorial was not user-friendly.

I was following the tutorial that can set the scheduler of compute instance so that my scraper can work and close at given time.

[Schduler tutorial of gcp]
https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule

In this tutorial, process works as follows:
1. Set the scheduler to call the Pubsub
2. Pubsub send message to Cloud Functions
3. Cloud wakes and closes the compute instance
*4. I turned on the compute engine at 23:50, and used cron inside the compute engine to run my scraper at 00:00, and finally turned off the compute engine at 1:00.

I will skip all the non-problematic lines of script, but only deal with that made me sick for few days.

After setting, compute instances, pubsub, you have to deploy the functions.

```
gcloud functions deploy startInstancePubSub \
    --trigger-topic start-instance-event \
    --runtime nodejs6

gcloud functions deploy stopInstancePubSub \
    --trigger-topic stop-instance-event \
    --runtime nodejs6
```

At here, it says runtime nodejs6, but you have to set it to nodejs8, since nodejs6 has beed depracated and this tutorial don't mentions that.

After, you have to test that functions are callable.

```
gcloud functions call stopInstancePubSub \
    --data '{"data":"eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtd2VzdDEtYiIsImluc3RhbmNlIjoid29ya2RheS1pbnN0YW5jZSJ9Cg=="}'
```

--data parameter needs the json format data which is encoded into 'base64' like follows.

```
echo '{"zone":"us-west1-b", "instance":"workday-instance"}' | base64

eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtd2VzdDEtYiIsImluc3RhbmNlIjoid29ya2RheS1pbnN0YW5jZSJ9Cg==
```

However when I followed the instruction, it returned the error of

```
gcloud functions call stopInstancePubSub \              
    --data '{"data":"eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtd2VzdDEtYiIsImluc3RhbmNlIjoid29ya2RheS1pbnN0YW5jZSJ9Cg=="}'
error: |-
  Error: function execution failed. Details:
  Attribute 'label' missing from payload
```

Since I was not used to gcp, had no idea of what 'label' meant. But by following the comments from @JohnHanley, I changed the line to

```
echo '{"zone":"asia-northeast2-a", "label":"env:dev", "instance":"workday-instance"}' | base64

eyJ6b25lIjoiYXNpYS1ub3J0aGVhc3QyLWEiLCAibGFiZWwiOiJlbnY6ZGV2IiwgImluc3RhbmNlIjoid29ya2RheS1pbnN0YW5jZSJ9Cg==

gcloud functions call stopInstancePubSub --data '{"data":"eyJ6b25lIjoiYXNpYS1ub3J0aGVhc3QyLWEiLCAibGFiZWwiOiJlbnY6ZGV2IiwgImluc3RhbmNlIjoid29ya2RheS1pbnN0YW5jZSJ9Cg==
"}'
```

And this worked like magic. Although I haven't set the labels of the functions, but it worked anyway. But to be completely sustainable, I set the labels of the function to "env:dev" to be sure.

This actually extends to the lines below:

```
gcloud beta scheduler jobs create pubsub startup-workday-instance \
    --schedule '0 9 * * 1-5' \
    --topic start-instance-event \
    --message-body '{"zone":"us-west1-b","instance":"workday-instance"}' \
    --time-zone 'America/Los_Angeles'
```

In this message-body "label" is missing. I tested the 'with--label-message-version' and 'without-label-message-version', turned out that although 'without version' showed the message that 'I did what you asked for', but actually it didn't